# How can I append 2 button to textarea and align them automatically using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I want to add 2 button to the right of textarea,one on top and another under it using bootstrap and align them automatically,is it possible to achive with just using orignal bootstrap class?

with https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/ showed example I can code some like :

```
<div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">With textarea</span>
</div>
<textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
    <div class="input-group-append" id="button-addon4">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

which showed:
[image: ss]
But I want it like:
[image: ss]
and align them automatically (and maybe adjust their size by the size of textarea auto?)
so is there a way could done it by just using orignal bootstrap class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `d-flex flex-column` on `#button-addon4` div and also apply `flex: 1 0 auto;` on the buttons to expand button's height when the textarea's height is increased.

```css
.input-group-text,
.btn-outline-secondary {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">With textarea</span>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column" id="button-addon4">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="input-group mt-4">
    <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
    <div class="input-group-append d-flex flex-column">
      <span class="input-group-text">Button 1</span>
      <span class="input-group-text">Button 2</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bootstrap grid to take textarea and buttons side by side.
And For buttons use the same width to your parent div and buttons and use display property with the inline-block option.

As Shown down below

**HTML :**

```
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <span class="input-group-text">With textarea</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <textarea class="form-control" aria-label="With textarea"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group-append button-group" id="button-addon4">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button> 
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.button-group {
    width: 70px;
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin-left: -28px !important;
}

.btn {
  width: 70px;
}
```

and here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/nick4434/pen/agKOqq?editors=1100) to view above code's output

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="d-flex">
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" resize="false"></textarea>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-1">Primary</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>
  </div>
</div>
```